# Truncate Null values in Python list

Tags: python, list

I have next structure shown below, I got it after

```
cur.execute('SELECT id, array_agg(row(id, name)) as list_names FROM bookie GROUP BY id')
result = cur.fetchall()
```

result['list_names'] returns

```
"{"(514,\"Fortuna CZ\")","(514,\"Fortuna CZ\")","(513,\"Tipsport CZ\")","(513,\"Tipsport CZ\")","(,)","(,)"}"
```

A couple of question below:

1. How can I truncate NULL-values ("(,)","(,)") in Python?
2. How can I transform correctly result['list_names'] to simple list or tuple, as shown below?

   [(514, 'Fortuna CZ'), (513, 'Tipsport')..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your query to exclude the empty fields by adding a condition:

```
WHERE name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I find a Python way

Comment: @Oleksandr a "Pythonic" way is indeed to not bring data you don't want into it to start with... so if it can be done in postgres, then it's best to do it there, what if there were a billion rows that needed excluding, best to not just have them to start with, right? :p

Comment: I agree with you about filtering in DB side, but I want to know about Python way

Answer (score 0):

Try

newresult = [x for x in result if x != '']